# How to calculate two numbers after pressing on equal sign and a few numbers without pressing on equal sign, like this: '12 + 7 - 5 * 3'?

Tags: javascript, function, frontend, calculator

I'm building a calculator in javascript and I have problem with operations. If user input 12 + 7 - 5 * 3, result should be 42. So user should click 12 + 7 and result should come out, then when user click - 7 result should come out and so on. I can't come up with the right solution for that.

```
operator.forEach((oper) =>
  oper.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    choosenOp = e.target.innerText;
    firstNumber = +display.innerText;
    secondNumber = +numbers.innerText.charAt(0);
    console.log(`First number: ${firstNumber}`);
    console.log(`Second number: ${secondNumber}`);

    if (numbers.innerText && display.innerText) {
      firstNumber = numbers.innerText.charAt(0);
      console.log(firstNumber);
      secondNumber = display.innerText.slice(1);
      display.innerText = display.innerText.toString().slice(1);
      console.log(secondNumber);
      display.innerText = operate(choosenOp, +firstNumber, +secondNumber);
    }
    // display.innerText = 0;
    display.innerText = operate(choosenOp, +firstNumber, +secondNumber);
    console.log(operate(choosenOp, +firstNumber, +secondNumber));
    numbers.innerText = `${firstNumber}${choosenOp}`;
  })
);

equalOp.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  secondNumber = +display.innerText;
  console.log(`Second number: ${secondNumber}`);
  display.innerText = operate(choosenOp, +firstNumber, +secondNumber);
});
```

Comment: FWIW, that shouldn't be 42 it should be 4.

Comment: @imvain2 op wants to evaluate the operation every time an operator is clicked, it should be 42

Answer (score -2):

- the answer is not 42 should be 4:
- You must follow the precedence list:
- Python Operators Precedence Rule - PEMDAS

1. P – Parentheses.
2. E – Exponentiation.
3. M – Multiplication.
4. D – Division.
5. A – Addition.
6. S – Subtraction.

you can find more detailed information at the next video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7AixVRoo74

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).